How to perform mmrm model and get the lsmean results in loop in sas?
I am a R user and new to SAS. I tried to write a do loop to run MMRM model and append the results. So far I had a general idea to perform the loop, but still couldn't figure out how to implement it in SAS.
I have a dataset have including variables as:
subjid, treatment, baseline, visit, age_gr, gender_gr, bmi_gr
The steps that I want to run the loop are as below:
Step 1: set the name=age_gr, and generate a empty data called result;
Step 2: run the MMRM model where &name=1 as below:
proc mixed data = have;
     where &name=1;
     class subjid treatment visit;
     model chg = baseline treatment visit treatment*visit/ ddfm = KR;
     repeated visit/ subject = subjid type = UN;
     lsmeans treat*visit/ cl alpha = 0.05 diff e;
     ods output lsmeans = lsmeans diffs=diffs;
     run;

Step 3: save the result of lsmeans and 95% CI using a macro called %format_result(lsmeans,diffs,&name); I have completed the macro, so just need to know the result was saved at a file called &name, i.e it should called age_gr in the first loop and the result looks like below:
&name    treatment_1    treatment_2    diffs(95%CI)        p-value
1        -1.10(0.02)   -0.40(0.06)     -0.71(-0.86,-0.57)  <.0001

Step 4: append the result &name to the data result as below:
data result;
set result &name;
run;

Step 5: run the MMRM model where &name=2 as below:
proc mixed data = have;
     where &name=2;
     class subjid treatment visit;
     model chg = baseline treatment visit treatment*visit/ ddfm = KR;
     repeated visit/ subject = subjid type = UN;
     lsmeans treat*visit/ cl alpha = 0.05 diff e;
     ods output lsmeans = lsmeans diffs=diffs;
     run;

Step 6:
Same as Step 3, save the result of lsmeans and 95% CI using a macro called %format_result(lsmeans,diffs,&name), and the result was saved at a file called &name and looks like below:
&name    treatment_1    treatment_2    diffs(95%CI)        p-value
2        -0.95(0.09)   -0.43(0.14)     -0.56(-0.91,-0.15)  0.01

Step 7:
Same as Step 4: append the result &name to the data result as below:
data result;
set result &name;
run;

Step 8：repeat step1-7 by setting the name=gender_gr;
Step 9: repeat step1-7 by setting the name=bmi_gr, and finally get the result file;
I was thinking of performing the loop using something like array in SAS but failed:
data want;
  set have;
  array vars age_gr--bmi_gr;
  do i=1 to dim(vars);
     name=vars(i);
     ... have no idea how to continue

Really appreciated if anyone can help!

You don't need to use SAS for this necessarily, try the mmrm R-package (at least for cross-checking your results) :-)

I think want to run PROC MIXED for each level of the _GR variables steps 1-7 can be achieved with a macro similar to this.
%macro main(name);
   proc sort data=have;
      by &name;
      run;
   proc mixed data=have;
     by &name;
     class subjid treatment visit;
     model chg = baseline treatment visit treatment*visit/ ddfm = KR;
     repeated visit/ subject = subjid type = UN;
     lsmeans treatment*visit/ cl alpha = 0.05 diff e;
     ods output lsmeans = lsmeans diffs=diffs;
     run;    
   %format_result(lsmeans,diffs,&name);
   %mend main;


Thanks a lot! It does help to simplify the code.

I've figured out how to run the loop. But I think it is not good enough since I have to input the colnames (age_gr gender_gr bmi_gr) to the macro one by one. The real dataset contains over 15 variables, so it would take a long time to input the colnames to the macro. If anyone could help to simplify the input procedure based on the code below, it would be great.
%macro outputResults(colnames=);

    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&colnames., %str( ) ));
        %let this_col = %sysfunc(scan(&colnames., &i., %str( ) ));

         proc sort data=have;
         by &this_col;
         run;

         proc mixed data = have;
         by &this_col;
         class subjid treatment visit;
         model chg = baseline treatment visit treatment*visit/ ddfm = KR;
         repeated visit/ subject = subjid type = UN;
         lsmeans treatment*visit/ cl alpha = 0.05 diff e;
         ods output lsmeans = lsmeans diffs=diffs;
         run;

          %format_result(lsmeans,diffs,&this_col); /*the macro will output a dataset called `&this_col`*/

         data output_&i.(rename=(&this_col=num));
             length group $10.;
             set &this_col;
             group = "&this_col.";
         run;
    %end;

    data all_results;
        set output_:;
    run;

    /* Remove temp data */
    proc datasets lib=work nolist;
        delete output_:
               lsmeans:
               diffs:
        ;
    quit;

%mend;

%outputResults(colnames=age_gr gender_gr bmi_gr)

